# How to language switch using Fn key?

Tags: keyboard, language

I have Mac Studio with M1, Ventura 13.3.
I also have wireless Apple keyboard, but fn key doesn't have globe.
Can I use fn key for switching language? If I connect magic keyboard Fn key works of course, but I like my small Apple keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **System Settings > Keyboard**. Then, open the menu next to “**Press fn key to**” and select "**Change Input Source**". This will make you able to change the keyboard language when pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. (See [Write in another language on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/write-in-another-language-on-mac-mchlp1406/13.0/mac/13.0) for more info and guidance on this)

The top picture below is for Ventura's new Settings format. The bottom one is for the Preferences format used in Monterey and earlier.

[image: Screenshot of the above-described setting in macOS Ventura's System Settings]

[image: Screenshot of the above-described setting in macOS Monterey's (and before) System Preferences]